# Video is overflow on mobile only

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a corner radius video using a container.
Works great on any browser on desktop, and on mobile video is overflow the container.

```css
.videoC {
  width: 70vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: calc(15vw - 4px);
  border-radius: 10vw;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 8px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoC">
  <video class="video" loop="loop" muted autoplay defaultMuted playsinline oncontextmenu="return false;" src="xxx"></video>
</div>
```

on mobile iOS safari, the video corners overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a Safari bug, solution, is it add this to the parent :

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a mobile version of your site.
you can use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
//
}
```

where:
@media is the css rule of css--
only screen and() is for set a "limit" of your rule
--max-width if for set the maximum width for your rule